# Mongoose.countDocuments is not working when counting documents by moment js that are created last year

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I am working on an open-source library called wertik-js and it uses Graphql, I have added reporting type helpers that return counting of mongoose models based on created at. Here in this case I have reportings like, total_count, total_added_last_year etc, total_added_today etc, For today I have filtered in this way:

```js
model.countDocuments(
  {
    created_at: {
      $gt: moment().startOf("day"),
      $lt: moment().endOf("day"),
    },
  },
  function (err, count) {
    resolve(count);
  }
);
```

And it works pretty fine. When using for last year, I have data created last year. Which counts in this way for last year

```js
model.countDocuments(
  {
    created_at: {
      $gt: moment().subtract(1, "year").startOf("year"),
      $lt: moment().subtract(1, "year").endOf("year"),
    },
  },
  function (err, count) {
    resolve(count);
  }
);
```

But last year count is not working and every time it returns 0 but I am sure I have written the query in right way and it returns the wrong number which is 0. Where total_added_today returns fine.

To reproduce the bug, you can pull this branch https://github.com/Uconnect-Technologies/wertik-js/tree/188-graphql-or-rest-api-enpoint-to-show-all-stats and:

1. Install packages and run the server sudo yarn && sudo yarn dev
2. Go to http://localhost:4000/
3. And execute the graphql query:

```
{
  roleStats {
    total_count
    total_added_this_month
    total_added_this_week
    total_added_last_7_days
    total_added_today
    total_added_last_month
    total_added_last_90_days
    total_added_last_year
    total_added_this_year
  }
}
```

And you will be able to reproduce the error.

You can check this file https://github.com/Uconnect-Technologies/wertik-js/blob/188-graphql-or-rest-api-enpoint-to-show-all-stats/src/framework/reporting/index.ts#L110 from line 110 mongoose starts.

What I am doing wrong here?

Any help will be considered as a contribution to this open-source project.

**Edit**

An example document I am searching:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed85b8893280c021c2ddfd6"
    },
    "name": "John",
    "created_at": "Thu Jun 04 2019 07:25:12 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)",
    "updated_at": "Thu Jun 04 2019 07:25:12 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Totally not going to pull a repo and build, but if you edit a sample document into the question that you believe the query should be finding, we might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Try using `.toDate()` with those moment objects in the condition

Comment: @Joe already tried that but that didn't help. An example document is added.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `created_at` field in the document contains a string: `"Thu Jun 04 2019 07:25:12 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"`

This is not sortable by date-time, or matchable with any date-range operators.

You might try converting those to dates with aggregation or update:

```
db.collection.update({created_at: {$type: "string"}},
                     [{$set: {created_at: {$toDate: {"$created_at"}}],
                     {multi:true})
```

Then you will be able to perform `$gt` or `$lt` tests meaningfully.

Comment: Can we set this in schema?

Comment: I am using mongoose

Comment: If you set the schema to use a date type instead of string that should solve it for new documents.  If you need to update the existing documents, it would probably be simplest to run the one-time update from the mongo shell.

Comment: It's not an issue regarding old posts, I am just testing the library reporting so the data is dummy. One question, I have used Date.now() milliseconds. Will it work with $gt and $lt?

Comment: MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive, if you store the dates as milliseconds, query them with milliseconds, if you store them as date objects, query them with date objects.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion with date object worked just fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
 $lt: moment().subtract(1, "year").endOf("year"),
```

it should be

```
      $lt: moment().endOf("year"),
```

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with `subtract(1, "year")`? I am just going one year back to fetch count for documents created last year.